# CodeClimate::TestReporter::InvalidPayload

Tags: ruby, travis-ci, gemfile, code-climate

I'm facing with the following problem, trying to execute code climate reporter on .travis.yml:

> Code Climate encountered an exception: CodeClimate::TestReporter::InvalidPayload No source files were found in the test report payload

Is there anybody here who could help me?

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
require "codeclimate-test-reporter"
CodeClimate::TestReporter.start
```

at the **beginning** of file `spec_helper.rb`.

Comment: This solves the problem and should be accepted so it helps anyone else who finds this question.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your spec_helper.rb file?
This error can be because of quite a few reasons :

- Calling SimpleCov.start and CodeClimate::TestReporter.start

  - Instead try SimpleCov.start CodeClimate::TestReporter.configuration.profile
- Add SimpleCov.formatter = SimpleCov::Formatter::MultiFormatter[
  SimpleCov::Formatter::HTMLFormatter,
  CodeClimate::TestReporter::Formatter
  ]
- So, the final spec_helper.rb is something like this :

  ```
  require "codeclimate-test-reporter" <br>
  require 'simplecov'

  SimpleCov.formatter = SimpleCov::Formatter::MultiFormatter[SimpleCov::Formatter::HTMLFormatter,CodeClimate::TestReporter::Formatter]

  dir = File.join("..", "coverage")
  SimpleCov.coverage_dir(dir)
  SimpleCov.start CodeClimate::TestReporter.configuration.profile
  ```